# Session abandoning

Tags: session, session-state, session-variables

I have 3 active Sessions in my website Session["name"], Session["lastname"] and Session["username"], does Session.Abandon() will abandon all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you have *one* active session (not *three*).  That session has those three key/value pairs associated with it.

Yes, Session.Abandon() will remove all of those variables in the process of abandoning the session, as soon as processing of the current page has finished.

> Once the Abandon method is called, the current session is no longer valid and a new session can be started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx

> When the Abandon method is called, the current Session object is queued for deletion but is not actually deleted until all of the script commands on the current page have been processed. This means that you can access variables stored in the Session object on the same page as the call to the Abandon method but not in any subsequent Web pages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx

**UPDATE**

If you want to "get rid of" the key/value pairs before the page finishes executing, you can clear them like this:

```
Session.Contents.RemoveAll()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524866(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the objects will be destroyed, but not immediately (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

> When the Abandon method is called, the current Session object is
>   queued for deletion but is not actually deleted until all of the
>   script commands on the current page have been processed. This means
>   that you can access variables stored in the Session object on the same
>   page as the call to the Abandon method but not in any subsequent Web
>   pages.

It is one session and 3 variables. If you need to remove them ASAP make them point to *null* and the data will immediately become subject for GC (which is not deterministic).

```
Session["name"] = null;
Session["lastname"] = null;
Session["username"] = null;
```

Comment: is there anything that I can do to abandon them, like I can't access variables stored in the Session object on the same page as the call to the Abandon?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it destroys all the objects stored in a Session object and releases their resources.